# No password prompt for serial connection

Tags: password, tty, serial-console, getty, minicom

I want to setup a password prompt (root user) when login through minicom (serial connection). After running passwd command (connected through ssh), i can setup a password for the root user. After that I will be asked for a password with every ssh connection. But unfortunately not when I connect serially. Any idea how I can setup password prompt for serial connection?

Comment: What are you presented with over that serial connection, instead?  You need to explain this in the question because the norm for local terminals on serial devices are a log on and a password prompt.  As long as you properly log off before switching off the terminal, that is.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564944/5132

Answer (score 0):

What are you presented with over that serial connection, instead?

1.) I run 'mincom' (on a computer that is serially connected to the device)

2.) then i see the minicom

Welcome to minicom 2.7

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Nov 15 2018, 20:18:47.
Port /dev/ttyUSB1, 08:17:28

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

3.) then I press Enter and am immediately connected serially on the device.

root@alfi:~# –